# Ignore full path for specific files when running 'tar' task in ant

Tags: ant, tar

I have my proj structure like this

```
 myproj
   -bin/myproj-run
   -bin/myproj-cli
   -lib/x.jar
   -target/myproj.jar
```

I want to create a tar.gz that looks like

```
myproj
       -bin/myproj-run
       -bin/myproj-cli
       -lib/x.jar
       -myproj.jar
```

How do I do it using ant tar task ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This one should work (I've tested this on my computer and it works):

```
<project name="tar.test" default="tartest">

    <dirname property="basedir" file="${ant.file.tar.test}" />

    <target name="tartest">
        <tar destfile="${basedir}/files.tar">
            <tarfileset dir="${basedir}/myproj">
                <exclude name="target/**" />
            </tarfileset>
            <tarfileset dir="${basedir}/myproj/target"/>
        </tar>
    </target>

</project>
```

BTW, you should read `tar` manual on [apache page](http://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/tar.html), you will find there few examples which shoud help you.

Answer (score 0):

I would first [`<copy>`](http://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/copy.html) the files to some other directory (e.g., one called 'package') with the folder structure that you want.  Then, run `<tar>` and `<gzip>`:

```
<tar destfile="myTar.tar" basedir="package" />
<gzip src="myTar.tar" destfile="myTar.tar.gz"/>
```